# Getting hashes of different length

Tags: php, mysql, hash, varchar, salt

When I store my hashed password, it goes in as `29` characters, but when I hash for the password validation it is `64`. The first `29` characters match, but I either need to lengthen the stored hash or shorten the validation hash. I have looked around the net and SO but can't seem to explicitly find out how to do this.

Which option (lengthen or shorten) is preferable and how would I go about doing this?

Here is my hash storage:

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $password1);

function createSalt(){
    $text = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($text, 0, 3);
}

$salt = createSalt();
$password = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);
```

and here is my password validation and echoing of the hashes (which don't match up):

```
$userData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );

if($hash != $userData['password']) // Incorrect password.
{ echo $userData['password'];
echo $hash;
    die ('incorrect password : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Thanks for any help, I sincerely appreciate it!

Comment: You definitely need to lengthen the hash field in your table.

Comment: So lengthen the varchar or whatever column type you`re using

Comment: But if you\`re using php 5.5 you\`d be better to use the inbuilt hash function.

Comment: ohhh. dang. that is silly. totally forgot that I had a limit on the varchar. Thanks!

Comment: ill look into the built in hash as well.

Comment: Please have a look at the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function to create a 60 character BCrypt hash. The used SHA-* algorithm is not appropriate to hash passwords, because it is ways too fast.